connection to service named com.apple.FileProvider"
in my application that I developed with Objective-C, I have a web view structure in which I select a photo from the photo gallery and upload it while testing it on my device with Xcode 16 and iOS 18 installed, but when I try to select and upload a photo from the photo gallery, I receive the following error in the log [ERROR] Could not create a bookmark: NSError: Cocoa 4097 "connection to service named com.apple.FileProvider". Has anyone encountered this error before? Thank you in advance.
I changed the product name based on an article stating that this error would be resolved by changing the product name. it didn't work again

As for my understanding (I'm not a dev), when faced with that kind of errors (FP, Cocoa), it usually could point to a few things:

App blocked from accessing fp/cocoa (perms)
Network/connectivity/not enough required system resources
FP/Cocoa is failing and restarting but the app cannot resume the connection with service.

I know that's not a lot, but hopefully, it will point you in the right direction.
